# ALAsset Video Compression

Tags: iphone, ios, video, uiimagepickercontroller, alasset

I've looked through SO and couldn't find a working answer for this question. I have created a custom image picker using ALAssets, but now that it's not the regular imagepicker there is no auto-compression of video.

This is how I am getting the video NSData from the asset:

```
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
    NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
    data = [[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES] retain];
```

Now the problem is, when I choose a large video file, the app crashes, because it receives memory warnings. Is there anyway to compress the video or even trim so the video file wouldn't be so large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with large videos. You should repeatedly copy just a small amount of bytes into the buffer from the asset and append it into the video data.